# $(O_K/pO_K)^p＝O_K/pO_K$holds, then $∃b∈K^×$, such that $｜a-b^p｜≦｜p｜$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $L$ be finite extension of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ and field $K$ satisfies $L⊆K⊆\Bbb{C}_p$.Let $O_K$ be ring of integers of $K$.
Suppose $(O_K/pO_K)^p＝O_K/pO_K$・・・① holds, then $∃b∈K^×$, such that $｜a-b^p｜≦｜p｜$.
How can I take such $b$?

I want to use the condition ①(in particular surjectivity to prove existence of $b$), but $｜｜$ disturbs me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b$ is any element of $O_K$ such that $b^p=a\in O_K/(p)$.

$b^p -a=0\in O_K/(p)$ means that $b^p-a\in (p)$ ie. $|b^p-a|\le |p|$